# EXCEL FUNCTIONS - SUMIFS - criteria based on the difference of 2 ranges (matrix)

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to get a function that return the sum of a calculated range comparison. Quick Example on the picture [image: here]

The goal is to find a formula that could get rid of the 3rd column (intermediary calculation). My data is on 2 different worksheet (real project).

I have tried a few combinations of formulas looking like:

`=sumifs((H4:H13)-(J4:J13),((H4:H13)-(J4:J13)),">0")`

however, I couldn't find the correct syntax.

Best,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Try following formulas ..

```
SUMPRODUCT(((H4:H13)-(J4:J13)>0)*((H4:H13)-(J4:J13)))
SUMPRODUCT(((H4:H13)-(J4:J13)=0)*((H4:H13)-(J4:J13)))
SUMPRODUCT(((H4:H13)-(J4:J13)<0)*((H4:H13)-(J4:J13)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems to work! I would prefer a sumifs function but I am not sure it's feasible.